# Why do I see the error page while trying to log in using Google Chrome browser?

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, google-openid

I have been encountering errors since today (`Jul 25`) morning while trying to log in to Stack Overflow.

1. Like I do everyday, I navigated to Stack Overflow log in page from my browser's (*Chrome*) bookmark manager. I use Google account to log in to Stack Overflow. Refer screenshot **#1**.
2. Since today (`Jul 25`) morning, I have to hit the *Enter* button twice or click the *Sign in* button to commence the log in process. Refer screenshot **#2**.
3. After logging in, I am taken to the Confirm page. This happened even after I cleared my browser cache by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Delete` and clearing every thing from the beginning of time, which I hoped would be sufficient enough! Refer screenshot **#3** and **#4**.
4. Every time I click the *Log In* button on the *Confirm* page, I get to see the most knowledgeable cat I have ever seen. Sometimes, the top level profile links appear correctly with my user name, refer screenshot **#5**. If I click on my profile, I am able to get to the web site. However, sometimes I don't see all the links at the top section. Refer screenshot **#6**.
5. **`EDIT 1:`** Screenshot **#7** shows same type of error occurs even while trying to log in through meta. Screenshot **#8** shows the content settings on my browser and screenshot **#9** shows the cookies currently saved on my machine. I have Windows XP SP3 installed on one laptop and Windows 7 on another laptop. The browser settings haven't changed and it has been the same for long time.
6. **`EDIT 2:`** I was finally able to fix the issue on the Windows XP machine by completely uninstalling Google Chrome and re-installing it. That worked. Now, I am trying the same on Windows 7 laptop.

I always use *Chrome* to access Stack Overflow. I do access the web site through either of my two laptops. Does that have anything to do with this error? I did try clearing the cache on both the machines but of no luck.

Is it just me or has any one else encountered this error?

I can get to the site eventually but this happens every time I log in.

**`EDIT 3:`** I am able to reproduce the error with the following sequence of events. This is what I have found after struggling with the error. Until recently, I have been mainly logging in to SO using Windows XP machine and very ocassionally using Windows 7 machine. It seems that logging in to both the machines at the same time causes this problem. Probably, yesterday was the first time I logged in to both machines at the same time. That's why I am having this issue since yesterday.

**`Sequence of events:`**

- Windows XP and Windows 7 machine had Google Chrome installed to begin with.
- I faced the issue as described in this question.
- Uninstalled Chrome from Windows XP laptop.
- Cleared all temp files and registry entries on Windows XP laptop using CCleaner.
- Re-installed Chrome on **Windows XP** machine and no changes were made to browser settings.
- Only action carried out on the browser after re-install was to import my old bookmark manager settings.
- Tried to log in to SO. `No issues` and everything worked as I expected it to work.
- Uninstalled Chrome from Windows 7 laptop.
- Cleared all temp files and registry entries on Windows 7 laptop using CCleaner.
- Re-installed Chrome on **Windows 7**  and no changes were made to browser settings.
- Only action carried out on the browser after re-install was to import my old bookmark manager settings.
- Tried to log in to SO. `Error occurs` again as explained earlier. Now, Windows XP machine also is not working.
- Closed the browsers on both the machines.
- Re-opened the browsers on both the machines and pressed `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Delete` to clear the browser cache.
- On Windows 7 machine tried to log in to SO, same error.
- Ran CCleaner on both Windows XP and Windows 7 machines to clear all temporary files, caches and invalid registry entries. I have selected every option in CCleaner except Wipe Free Space.
- On Windows 7 machine tried to log in to SO again, same error.
- Now, I am back to square one.

Is this an expected behavior when accessing SO from two different machines at the same time?

**Screenshots:**

**#1:** SO log in page.

[image: SO log in page]

**#2:** Google accounts log in page

[image: Google accounts log in page]

**#3:** Log in confirm

[image: Log in confirm]

**#4:** Clear browsing data

[image: Clear browsing data]

**#5:** Something bad has happened with all the top level links

[image: Something bad has happened with all the top level links]

**#6:** Something bad has happened without all the top level links

[image: Something bad has happened without all the top level links]

**#7:** I miss Zoe, the Cat

[image: I miss Zoe, the Cat]

**#8:** Browser settings

[image: Browser settings]

**#9:** Cookies on the local machine

[image: Cookies on the local machine]

Comment: Why did you black-out your rep/badges? It's [public info](http://stackoverflow.com/users/756519/siva)

Comment: @Michael Mrozek, if you really want to know, just view her profile...

Comment: @Ham You mean the one I linked to?

Comment: Yep. I suppose @Siva is a little modest.

Comment: +1 So many nice pictures.

Comment: Looking into it - seeing some oddities in the logs and trying to repro.

Comment: What version of XP were you using when you were having these issues? And is this OS running normally or is it virtualized?

Comment: Also, on the right side of the address bar, what is that cookie icon with a red X?

Comment: Seems that's the "block cookies by default" setting in chrome - but you're getting our cookies, since we see you're logging in.

Comment: I'm not even able to log in with Google with the `chrome://settings/content` -> Cookies -> **Block sites from setting any data**, even after allowing both Google and Stack Overflow - can you try changing that setting back to **Allow local data to be set** and logging in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we send you off to your OpenID provider for authentication, we save where you should be returned to in session state; this "return to" url was improperly encoded for certain urls and caused Chrome to not redirect you back.

This will be fixed in the next build.